# Chmod not working?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm running this very simple code:

```
echo chmod('file_permissions.php', 0664);
echo decoct(fileperms('file_permissions.php'));
```

I want to make clear that SAFE MODE is OFF, and that im working on windows, running apache on XAMPP server.

Any ideas about what might be going on?

Update: It only works with the mods 0444 and 0666, anything else doesn't have any effects, i.e. 0777 gets set to 0666.... so odd.

Comment: Because it's windows. `chmod` is useful for setting permissions in Linux, however the windows permission system is set up differently, so chmod will never yield the expected results.

Comment: Thank you jon, what is window's permissions system called?

Comment: To be able to modify the permissions from within PHP?  The way to make sure you'll get it right is to `exec` to `xcacls.exe` or similar method. Technically, `chmod` does work, but is a lot trickier in windows, as 'group' is never really assigned to a file directly, rather different groups have different permissions, etc...